# How to properly add listener for a control in controller?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I can successfully add a listener to the `painted` event in the view for a `selectfield`. But, how do I do this in the controller?

```
control: {
    "#form #field": {
        painted: 'onPainted'
    }
}
// omitted onPainted method that logs message in console
```

This doesn't work. However, directly adding a listener in the view works.

```
// in the view for the selectfield (works)
listeners: {
    painted: function() {
        console.log("Painted");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a comment in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.field.Select-event-painted):

> This event is not bubbled up to the controller, "for performance reasons".

Comment: Ah, so it's just this event in particular. Thanks for the reference. I've actually been looking at the docs, but didn't bother to look at the comments.